# Backbone router is not routing "new" route correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am trying to use Backbone for my latest Rails project, and the latest issue I am facing is with routes.

For my Rails routing, I have users go to /products (index_products_path) after signing in.

So, I created the following routes in Backbone. I intend to create other Backbone routers for different "pages" (like invitation).

```
class Sample.Routers.ProductsRouter extends Backbone.Router

  routes:
    ""         : "index"
    ":id"      : "show"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    "new"      : "newProduct"
```

"mydomain.com/products" bring up index view. "mydomain.com/products/#/1" or "mydomain.com/products#1" bring up show view with product id = 1.

Now, the problem is for "new" path. When I use try to bring up "new" view by pointing to "mydomain.com/products#new", the server complains that it cannot find a product with id=new.

I really can't figure out why this might be happening. When I traced error stack, I could see that `Sample.Routers.ProductsRouter.ProductsRouter.show` is being called. It seems like Backbone Router is not routing this correctly..... and Rails server is just responding to "GET" request for product with id=new........  Could it be some sort of Backbone configuration error?

Any help would be very, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone execute the first matching route. So in your case, just put `new` first.

```
  routes:
    ""         : "index"
    "new"      : "newProduct"
    ":id"      : "show"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
```

Comment: Thank your, Simon, for the quick answer! Now I feel pretty silly for not knowing pretty trivial stuff. :(

Comment: There's no guarantee that this will work everywhere (or anywhere for that matter), JavaScript objects are unordered so any order you see is accidental. If you require your routes to be checked in a specific order then you must add them manually using [`route`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route) calls.

Comment: @muistooshort By the standard you're right, although every actual browsers loops over an object in order currently (Chrome had a bug with this back in 2008 if I'm correct). I guess that to stick by the current standard, it would by best practice to "namespace" any route variable with a forename; e.g. `product/:id`